# Reference for Stasheff's Associahedra Operad

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces, operads

I am currently reading up on operads and am more than confused about the Stasheff operad. It is completely unplausible that I am the first student, who feels this way, so I hope to find a reference explaining to me the following questions in detail.

1. The $n$-th Stasheff Polytope $K_n$ (aka associahedron) is

   - "*the convex polytope with one vertex for each way of inserting parantheses into $n$ letters*"
   - or "*the convex polytope with one vertex for each regular triangulation of a regular $n$-gon $C_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$*"
   - or "*the convex polytope with one vertex for each binary rooted trees with $n$ leafs*".

   Intuitively clear, but not formal. In line with the second reformulation, the construction of the space $K_n$ as secondary polytope makes the most sense to me, since it is easy to verify that a (continuous) section of the canonical morphism $\Delta^{n-1}\rightarrow C_n, e_i \mapsto v_i$ amounts to a triangulation of $C_n$ (more details on this construction [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421918/secondary-polytope)). Assuming a convenient category of spaces in the background, there already is a space of such sections. So how do we motivate taking the barycenters of sections (a posteriori this somehow gives us a convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$, but a priory it is not clear to me, why this is the canonical thing to do)?
2. Why is it clear from this description that $K_n$ always has dimension $n-2$?
3. Most sources I could find just state that the family $(K_n)_n$ of associahedra assemble into a non-symmetric operad. If I am not mistaken, one should specify a bit more than the objects to define an operad. The most detailed description I could find was [MSS - Operads in Algebra, Topology and Physics](http://theo.inrne.bas.bg/%7Emitov/configuration/Markl%20M.,%20Shnider%20S.,%20Stasheff%20J.D,%20Operads%20in%20Algebra,%20Topology%20and%20Physics,%202002.pdf) section 1.6, where they claim without proof that

   - the $d$-dimensional cells of $K_n$ are of the form $\prod_{i=1}^k K_{n_i}$, where $d=n_1 + ... + n_k -2k$
   - the facets (i.e. cells of codimension 1, i.e. cells of dimension $n-3$) are of the form $K_r \times K_s$ with $r+s=n+1$

   Again, why is that clear? How do we obtain these facet-embeddings from above description? The operad structure then is given by defining the circle products $\circ_i: K_r \times K_s \subseteq K_{r+s-1}$, which somehow suffices to define the whole operad structure. (I still have to read up on that last part. It seems plausible that this suffices, the only thing worrying me, is that I read somewhere that you cannot always define an operad in this way...)
4. If I am not mistaken, most definitions ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad#Definition), [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/operad#definition_in_components)) of an operad involve a unit, i.e. contain a choice of element $1 \in \mathcal{O}(1)$ satisfying unitality conditions. I have the wild guess that also the definition of an operad [as a monoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/operad#DefinitionAsMonoid) involves a unit. Problem is: some sources say that the Stasheff operad is non-unital i.e. doesn't have a unit. (I mean, fair, if one doesn't specify any structure whatsoever, in particular no unit is given, making it canonically non-unital by omission...). This leads to the question, if I define operads to always be unital, is the Stasheff operad even an operad? Or can I at least make it unital?

**Remarks**

- I don't really care, whether the $K_n$ is a convex polytope or not, for my purposes it would suffice to have an explicit CW-complex of the right dimension. I've heard that you can describe $K_n$ as the space of weighted planar embedded rooted trees with $n$ leafs, where you weight the inner edges by values in the range $[0,1]$. I could not find it in the literature and am unsure, how the topology is defined *explicitly*. It would clear up points 2. and 3. however, by counting inner edges and grafting trees onto each other.
- The name *Stasheff operad* is probably non-standard, but to be honest I don't know a better name. [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141363/reference-for-stasheff-operad) link is related to my question, but doesn't answer it.

Comment: You are asking many different questions in one post, and it would be better if you could try to focus on one at a time. Did you read [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212126) paper? Did you read Stasheff's original paper? Do any of those help?

Comment: I chose to ask all this questions at once, since I hoped that *anybody* wrote out the operad in full (hopefully readable) detail. I tried to read Stasheff's paper, but the construction of the $K_n$ there is quite mysterious to me and he doesn't talk about the operad structure (yes its implicit, but I search for a resource on the explicit description. There is no hope he answers 4). Searching for constructions of $K_n$ I came across Loday's paper. But I don't think the questions above are answered there explicitly either...

Comment: I mean everything above is folklore and can probably retrieved from the literature (with considerable effort). I will be happy to do that if no one knows a good reference. But in the light that this is one of the first operads mentioned (but not written out) in ANY introduction to operads, I find it hard to believe I will be the first one to do so...

Comment: Did you try looking in Boardman-Vogt? See also [Iwase](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5741) and the references therein.

Comment: @Tyrone thank you, I was unaware of both references. I will look them up.

Comment: For future reference, there is a nice description of the associahedra in Loday+Vallette's Algebraic Operads Appendix C (https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_3121746_1/component/file_3121747/content). A full description of the analogous categorical operad (ie. Operad in Cat) can be found in Fiedorowicz et al Associahedra and Weak Monoidal Structures on Categories (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.3979.pdf)